# Find matches between a list and dataframe column

Tags: pandas

I want to create a filter in pandas dataframe and print specific values like failed if all items are not available in dataframe.

**data.csv content:**

```
server,ip
server1,192.168.0.2
data,192.168.0.3
server3,192.168.0.100
server4,192.168.0.10
```

I created below code:

```
import pandas as pd

l = ['server1','server2']
ip_list = ['192.168.0.2','192.168.0.100','192.168.25.4']

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
#count = ip_list.count()


data_filter = data[
    (data['ip'].isin(ip_list) ) 
]

print(data_filter)
```

Above code is printing result as below:

```
    server             ip
0  server1    192.168.0.2
2  server3  192.168.0.100
```

I need help to print result as below

```
    server             ip   Status
0  server1    192.168.0.2    Success
2  server3  192.168.0.100   Success
3  NA         192.168.25.4  Failed
```

Please guide me how can I create this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) + [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) functions:

```
df_filtered = (df.merge(pd.DataFrame(ip_list, columns=['ip']), 
                       on='ip', how='right', indicator='Status'))
df_filtered['Status'] = df_filtered['Status'].map({'both': 'Success', 'right_only': 'Failed'})
```

---

```
    server             ip   Status
0  server1    192.168.0.2  Success
1  server3  192.168.0.100  Success
2      NaN   192.168.25.4   Failed
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd

l = ['server1','server2']
ip_list = ['192.168.0.2','192.168.0.100','192.168.25.4']

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
#count = ip_list.count()


data['Status'] = list(map(lambda x: 'Success' if x else 'Failed', data['ip'].isin(ip_list)))

print(data)
```